# Ошибка php Парсер

Tags: php, парсер

Возникла ошибка при выполнение кода:

```
<?php  
    require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';
    $content = file_get_contents('http://lineageii.uz/index.php?f=stat&act=general&sid=1');

    $dom = new DomDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'));

    $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
    $hel = $xpath->query("//td[@class='l2right']"); echo $hel[2]->nodeValue;
?>
```

Выводит результат:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 64 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 64 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 88 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 88 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 108 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 108 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 111 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 111 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 112 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 112 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 113 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 113 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 114 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 114 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 115 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 115 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID lastpost already defined in Entity, line: 150 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : a in Entity, line: 301 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 302 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: no name in Entity, line: 302 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 302 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : size in Entity, line: 324 in C:\WEB\OpenServer\domains\gto\test\test.php on line 5
```

В чём может быть ошибка?

Comment: Ошибка не в парсере, ошибка в документе, который парсер пытается распарсить. Что делать? да скорее всего ничего.

Comment: @KoVadim  В том то и дело что на другом сервере данный парсер отлично работает !

Comment: чудес не бывает. Может там другая версия библиотек/php или просто подавлен вывод предупреждений

Comment: @KoVadim подавлен вывод предупреждений
Можно об этом чуток по подробнее !

Answer (score 0):

В данный момент там статистика недоступна - нет возможности проверить. Но непонятно что в коде делает HTML-ENTITIES ошибка в том числе и в нем + до кучи отключить ошибки. И если используется DomDocument что там делает require_once 'simple_html_dom.php'; ?

Попробуй такой код

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://lineageii.uz/index.php?f=stat&act=general&sid=1');

$dom = new DomDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($content);
libxml_clear_errors();

$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
$hel = $xpath->query("//td[@class='l2right']"); echo $hel[2]->nodeValue;
```

Кракозябры могут встречаться из-за gzip, вариант решения

```
$content = file_get_contents('compress.zlib://'.'http://lineageii.uz/index.php?f=stat&act=general&sid=1');
```

или передавать заголовок Accept-Encoding: deflate тогда большинство отдает без компрессии